# In Mark 1:13 & Matthew 4:11 were the "angels" (ἄγγελοι) שְּׂרָפִ֔ים Serafim, כְּרֻבִ֖ים Keruvim, מַלְאָכִים֙ יְהֹוָ֥ה Mal'akim HaShem, Torah Scrolls?

Tags: matthew, mark, angels

In Mark 1:13 & Matthew 4:11 were the "angels" ( ἄγγελοι ) considered שְּׂרָפִ֔ים Serafim, or כְּרֻבִ֖ים Keruvim, or מַלְאָכִים֙ יְהֹוָ֥ה Mal'akim HaShem, or Torah Scrolls perhaps, or some new branch of messengers?

Mark 1:13 [NASB]

> [13] And He was in the wilderness for forty days, being tempted by Satan; and He was with the wild animals, and the [angels] were serving Him.

Matthew 4:11 [NASB]

> [11] Then the devil *left Him; and behold, [angels] came and began to serve Him.

Answer (score 1):

Earlier in Matthew 4:

> 5Then the devil took him to the holy city and had him stand on the highest point of the temple. 6“If you are the Son of God,” he said, “throw yourself down. For it is written:
>
> “ ‘He will command his **angels** concerning you,
> and they will lift you up in their hands,
> so that you will not strike your foot against a stone.’ ”

After refusing to request the service of these angels, angels showed up without request (NASB):

> 11
> Then the devil left Him; and behold, angels came and **began to minister** to Him.

ministered
διηκόνουν (diēkonoun)
Verb - **Imperfect Indicative** Active - 3rd Person Plural
Strong's 1247: From diakonos; to be an attendant, i.e. Wait upon (figuratively) teacher; technically, to act as a Christian deacon.

It is better to classify these angels by their function and not by their class since the Bible does not specify their class labels.
These were ministering or attending angels that stayed with Jesus for a while in the imperfect tense of time until this particular job was done. I don't think they were particularly powerful angels.